# Why are my pair of budgies fighting?

Tags: behavior, breeding, birds

My pair of budgies were doing fine with their first clutch.
2 out of 5 eggs hatched so far and I am expecting the next egg to hatch tomorrow. 
However, just this morning I found my hen fighting with her mate, and refuses to let him anywhere near the nest box. I isolated the male, but would want to know why/ how this happened. They seemed to have gotten along just fine until now.

Also, would my hen be able to raise potentially 5 chicks on her own?

Comment: You have two questions here. Would you mind asking the second one as a new question? That might help people find it better.

Comment: My male and female budgies began to fight when their two new babies were ready to leave the nest. At first I thought the male was trying to mate, but it doesn't look like that. It appears that the female wants him to leave the babies alone now ...